# How to find client's IP Address using Javascript code

Tags: javascript, ip, ip-address

I want to find client's IP Address when accessing my app..How to find using javascript code..kindly provide help with sample code..I tried wit tis code but m not getting

> function getip(json){
>         alert(json.ip); // alerts the ip address
>       }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript  check this

Answer (score -1):

You can't using ONLY JavaScript on it's own. You need to use a server side script ans call it using Ajax to perform this task.

For example in PHP script, you can do the following to get the client's ip address:

```
echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Next call this script using Ajax and display/use it in your page.

Answer (score -1):

At least there used to be a way using Java to do this, but Javascript alone cannot find a machines IP.

Comment: Please leave a comment on down vote to indicate the reason ;) Otherwise it does not help ether the one who wrote the answer or any one reading it :D.  Also, if there is something wrong with my answer I am happy to delete it. The question asks for a pure Javascript solution client side which is not possible, the "duplicate" requires server side help which is not pure javascript either.